# Android image acceptable image size

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview

I'm drawing bitmaps to a surfaceView. I was wondering what the highest file size of a image may be before the fps gets affected?

Comment: There's no one answer.  The size will depend on the device.  On lower-end devices the size will be quite small, on higher end devices, you'll be able to get a much higher size without affecting the fps rate.

Comment: Ok, so lets say for G1 devices?